# Textarea loses focus when a rich editor is applied

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a HTML page with some pre-set options this work fine when I use a plain HTML Text-area, but when I use a rich editor such as "nicEditor" the Text area loses focus.

working page: **[Here](http://www.bulk-email-store.com/works.htm)**

no working page: **[Here](http://www.bulk-email-store.com/test.htm)**

Comment: The non working page doesn't contain a `textarea`

Comment: @andy That is not true – it is hidden via CSS.

Comment: @feeela - Yes but if you look at the source, you'll see the part you're actually entering text into is a div. I suspect the textarea is used for submitting the data.

Comment: @andy That is a very common way how richtext editors work in a webpage. See my answer below…

Comment: @feeela Oh right. I've never really dealt with rich text editors :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to set the value:

```
nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent('text');
```

Comment: Where? I cant figure it out.

Comment: @Bill It's javascript. In the working example, wherever you see `$mytextbox.val(...)` needs to be replaced with  `nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent(...)`.

Comment: yea that what I did with no luck see the demo page source.

Comment: It doesn't sounds like you know javascript or jquery. You should ask a programmer to do this for you.

Comment: I thought I was asking for help. If you look at the original and your update they do not work the same. Please refresh your browser and look. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have focus on a hidden element. To make my point clear: When using a richtext editor, you are not typing into the original textarea, but one that is provided by the editor (or even an `iframe`/`div` tag).

SO to have the focus on the editor window you need to set the focus to it, not to the textarea – which effectively get filled by JS.